# django template tag html safe escape not working for bold

Tags: django, html-escape-characters, templatetags

Hello there I´m trying to insert some bold style in a text and insert it throught django template tag variable. I tested and works with underline  and , but for  or  doesn´t !!

> Example:

in my database I have something saved like this :

```
objattribute.text = some <em>text</em> some text <b>some text</b> some text
```

and template tag

{{ objattribute.text|safe }}

> Result I´m getting :

some *text* some text some text some text

Any ideias about it??

Comment: Is this including the backticks? It might be helpful to share the *exact* string in `objattr.text`.

Comment: about backticks: I´ve removed them from the example... they´re not included in my original text... the exact string goes like this :
(CURY, Carlos Roberto Jamil; REIS, Magali; ZANARDI, Teodoro Adriano Costa. <b>Base Nacional Comum Curricular:</b> dilemas e perspectivas. São Paulo: Cortez, 2018.)
It´s portuguese, just in case ...

Comment: It´s a scientific work quotation ...

Comment: From the result you're getting it rather seems that `em` doesn't work, but in any case, I have just tested this string in Django 2.1 and `safe` works as expected.

Comment: yes, it´s working now, but the things is that my styles.css had a p * { font-weight : initial } directive overriding, that´s why the bold wasn´t showing!!